# how to turn an object of arrays into array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

the structure of the data axios gets is:

```
{
    "data": {
        "project": {
            "id": "5ebd525ea3ff2434c0d467f8",
            "items": [
                {
                    "name": "item one",
                    "size": 45,
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-14T14:15:43.034Z",
                },
                {
                    "name": "item two",
                    "size": 23,
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-14T14:15:58.508Z",
                },
                {
                    "name": "item one",
                    "size": 93,
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-14T15:02:19.889Z"
                },
                {
                    "name": "item two",
                    "size": 55,
                    "createdAt": "2020-05-19T02:48:14.486Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I need to accomplish is two things:

- Group the items by name
- map to new arrays to render in a chart

the code i have is

```
async created() {
      const response = await axios.get(
        `http://localhost:1337/projects/${this.routeId}`
      ))
      const { items } = response.data

  //returns new array of only fields needed to send to the chart
      const newArray = items.map(({name, size, createdAt}) => ({name, size, createdAt}))

 // group items by name **** this creates an object of arrays
      const groupBy = (array, key) => {
        return array.reduce((result, currentValue) => {
          (result[currentValue[key]] = result[currentValue[key]] || [])
          .push(currentValue);
          return result
        }, {})
      };
      const itemsGroupedByName = groupBy(newArray, 'name')

  //this fails *** trying to map an object into a new array
      itemsGroupByName.forEach(d => {
        const { name, size, createdAt } = d
        this.arrItemSize.push({
          date: moment(createdAt).format('MMM D YYYY'),
          total: size,
          name
        })
      })
    },
```

The code above groups the items as object of arrays -

```
{ [...], [...], [...], [...] }
```

The format the chart needs is array of objects

```
[ {...}, {...}, {...}, {...]
```

How do I map the grouped items to new arrays?
Thanks for any help

Comment: Can you explain more specifically what your output should look like?  And is it just a matter of wrapping `Object.values` around your output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function `Array.prototype.reduce` for grouping and the function `Object.values` for extracting the grouped objects.

*This is assuming the property `items` will contain the grouped objects.*

```js
let obj = {        "data": {            "project": {                "id": "5ebd525ea3ff2434c0d467f8",                "items": [                    {                        "name": "item one",                        "size": 45,                        "createdAt": "2020-05-14T14:15:43.034Z",                    },                    {                        "name": "item two",                        "size": 23,                        "createdAt": "2020-05-14T14:15:58.508Z",                    },                    {                        "name": "item one",                        "size": 93,                        "createdAt": "2020-05-14T15:02:19.889Z"                    },                    {                        "name": "item two",                        "size": 55,                        "createdAt": "2020-05-19T02:48:14.486Z"                    }                ]            }        }    };
let result = Object.values(obj.data.project.items.reduce((a, {name, ...rest}) => {
  (a[name] || (a[name] = {items: []}))["items"].push({name, ...rest});
  return a;
}, Object.create(null)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```